# Create an array to input multiple urls instead of the one I have I have now

Tags: php, arrays, dom

How can I modify the following code to get instead of the url of one xml, an array with multiple urls? The code below is working properly but as I said for one file.

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile ('domain.com/xmlfile.xml');

$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$posts = $xPath->query('//page');

foreach($posts as $post) {

$fans = $post->getElementsByTagName( "fan_count" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $fans;

}

?>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're opening XML documents using the `DOMDocument::loadHTMLfile` instead of [`DOMDocument::load`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php)?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use a `foreach` loop.

```
<?php

$files = array('file1.xml', 'file2.xml', 'file3.xml');

foreach ( $files as $file ) {
  $dom = new DOMDocument;
  $dom->loadHTMLFile($file);

  $xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);

  $posts = $xPath->query('//page');

  foreach($posts as $post) {
    $fans = $post->getElementsByTagName('fan_count')->item(0)->nodeValue;

    echo $fans;
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to loop over each file and extract the urls from each in turn. A DOMDocument object can handle only one single XML tree. Multiple XML files implies multiple document roots, which is not permitted.

I suppose you could create a "meta" XML document and insert each seperate file as a node off the meta XML's root node. Either way, slightly painful.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(0 => "url1", 1 => "url1");

for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
{


$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile ($arr[$i]);

$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$posts = $xPath->query('//page');

foreach($posts as $post) {

$fans = $post->getElementsByTagName( "fan_count" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $fans;

}
```

}